# Best Mechanism for Synchronizing Local Database and Remote Database[CLOUD] in Delphi

Tags: database, delphi, synchronization, delphi-2010, interbase

I have a **Delphi 2010** Application which store into **Local Database**[INTERBASE DB] and **remote DataBase** i.e Cloud [SQL Server] by framing respective query strings.

If in case of ***no internet connection*** , Application need to check **periodically** and post un-uploaded Local Database records to remote Database.

I found a ways to do,

1. Maintaining framed queries into a ***File/Table*** then periodically get and post to remote Database.

but how can i **effectively** update remote database with new data of local database when there is no internet connection?

thanks.

Comment: And what role Delphi 2010 plays in this?

Comment: What about an asynchronous message service? I don't know the Delphi counterpart of Java JMS/Message Driven Beans. If ther is no one, maybe you can call a Java service to do the task.